# Suppose f is a function such that f'(x) = 1/x for all x > 0. Prove that if f(1) = 0, then f(xy) = f(x) + f(y) for all x,y > 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose f is a function such that $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ for all $x > 0$. Prove that if $f(1) = 0, then f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$ for all $x,y > 0$

As stated above, how do i go about doing this question?

Hi all, i would like to apologize if the question is missing context or other details.

This question was part of my calculus tutorial.
I was on the topic of application of differentiation when this question was given to me.

Thus far i have learnt about intermediate value theorem, mean value theorem, rolle's theroem, Fermat's thereom.

As of this point in my learning, i have not touched upon integration. The only reason why i accepted the answer with integration in it was because i understood it.

Thus i believe i am suppose to use one the few theorems that i've stated to solve this question. But i have no idea where to start.

At first i differentiated the equation $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$ with respect to x

i believed the answer to be $f'(xy)\frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)+f'(y)\frac{dy}{dx}$

which would be $\frac{1}{xy}\frac{1}{x}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{x}$

At this point a few questions came to my mind 
1) am i suppose to differentiate the eqn in the first place
2) what has $f(1)=0$ got to do with anything
3) what theorem am i suppose to use to solve this question

This was my thought process throughout the question and i hope someone would point out my mistakes. Thank you

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $f(x) - f(1) = \int_1^x dt/t$. See where that leads you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integration. You can either use the fundamental theorem of calculus directly as shown by @Simon s, or else do the basic integration, and solve for the constant of integration later. I will do the latter. Notice that I use the variable $u$ initially. This is to prevent confusion with the second statement you give: $f(xy)=f(x)+f(y)$.
$$f'(u)=\frac{1}{u} \rightarrow \int \rightarrow f(u)=\ln(|u|)+C$$
$$f(1)=\ln(1)+C=0 \leftrightarrow 0+C=0 \rightarrow C=0$$
Therefore:
$$f(u)=\ln(|u|)$$
Since we have constrained: $x,y>0$, we can drop the absolute value signs at this point. At this point, we have the basic logarithm rule:
$$\ln(u*v)=\ln(u)+\ln(v)$$
Therefore, we say:
$$f(xy)=\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$$

Comment: I'm not absolutely certain, but I think the reason for said problem is to prove some properties of the logarithm. Maybe he can't directly directly use properties of the logarithm to justify this because it would be circular.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\phi(x) = f(xy)-f(x)-f(y)$. Note that $\phi(1) = 0$, and $\phi'(x) = 0$. Hence $\phi = 0$.

Comment: Feel free to ignore this, copper.hat. To anyone confused by how this approach let's us generalize to all $y$, it may be more apparent if the function $\phi$ is written as $\phi_y$. That is to say, this argument is valid for any $y$ and corresponding function $\phi_y$...i.e. for any $y$, the function $\phi_y$, as defined above, will be the constant function evaluating to $0$ everywhere where $x \gt 0$. So $\phi_4$ would show for all $x \gt 0$, $f(4x)=f(x)+f(y)$, $\phi_5$ would show for all $x \gt 0$, $f(5x)=f(x)+f(5)$, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $y\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and let $g(x)=f(xy)-f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$, then $g'(x)={y \over xy}-{1 \over x}=0$, so that $g(x)$ is constant. Let $x=1$, then by hypothesis, $g(1)=f(y)-f(1)=f(y)$, and the result immediately follows for any $x$.